# How to reuse a piece of XAML in a ContextMenu?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

Say that I have the following piece of XAML:

```
<Window>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label>Phone:</Label>
      <TextBlock Text={Binding PhoneNumber}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I would like to reuse this as the content of a ContextMenu. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `StackPanel` into a `UserControl`. This way you can reuse it.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for some other way (a resource?) as in my opinion a UserControl should me more generic, but it works very well!